# How do I make an `hr` with repeating small images?

Tags: css

I have an 256x256 image called `myImg.png`. I want to make an `hr` element that uses repeating 16x16 versions of `myImg.png`.

My CSS so far:

```
hr#target {
    border: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url(myImg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But this only shows two repetitions of my image at the full 256x256 size where I can only see 15px of it.

How do I make an `hr` where the background image is a row of small versions of `myImg.png`?

Comment: You should modify the image to 16x16 instead of using a really large image in my opinion.

Comment: One reasonable use case for something like this is a content management system where you have no control over the HTML but you do over the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) as in:

```
hr#target {
    border: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url(myImg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As @bjskistad mentioned, you should really be using an image that's already sized correctly.

Comment: Infact, he should resize the image and use `url(data:image/gif;base64,hashhere` as the image..